# I can't build an Atmel Studio 7 project with Arduino.h header file

Tags: c++, arduino, atmel, atmelstudio, attiny

I'm writing a code for an ATtiny841 which is using

```
<Arduino.h>
```

And when I click on Build (F7) I have this in the build window:

```
Severity Code Description Project File Line
Error  Arduino.h: No such file or directory
```

Then I try to include the Arduino header file I then I receive other issues in the code, saying that I have no such file or directory from other header files that I don't have, so I am asking if there is a way to include all of this libraries that came with the Arduino Header file  and how to do it, because this is driving me crazy, I don't want to include all files manually, this is only driving me to other issues in the code....

I want to use this library to interface with libraries that work with the Arduino header file to use it in the ATtiny841.

Comment: Sounds like the issue is a compiler options issue. In the include libraries section, did you check to make sure there is a path to the Arduino.h file?

Comment: Here is some tutorial on "importing" Arduino sketch  - http://blog.solutions-cubed.com/debugging-arduino-sketches-with-atmel-studio-7/ Note that you shall specify correct MCU model under Device. Probably you have to set F_CPU constant too for C++ compiler

Comment: Yes, I've been including libraries with the Solution Explorer, and then a receive another errors saying that is missed another header file **Inside** the Arduino header file.

Comment: The compiler options is not the solution explorer. These are settings for the project.